# Typescript: Array with arrays fails when using map

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
type Point = [number, number]
type Points = Array<Point>

const ok: Points = [[0, 0]]
const fail: Points = [0].map(() => [0, 0])
```

> Type 'number[][]' is not assignable to type '[number, number][]'.

Any ideas?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Point%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%0D%0Atype%20Points%20%3D%20Array%3CPoint%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ok%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C%200%5D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fail%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B0%5D.map(()%20%3D%3E%20%5B0%2C%200%5D)%0D%0A)

Comment: This works though `const fail: Points = [0].map(() => <Point>[0, 0])` [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Point%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%0D%0Atype%20Points%20%3D%20Array%3CPoint%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ok%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C%200%5D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fail%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B0%5D.map(()%20%3D%3E%20%3CPoint%3E%5B0%2C%200%5D)%0D%0A)

Comment: I think you need to explicitly define the map return type: `const fail: Points = [0].map<Point>(() => [0, 0])` Otherwise, map cannot exactly guess what the return type will be, since it's dynamic. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Point%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%0D%0Atype%20Points%20%3D%20Point%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ok%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C%200%5D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fail%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B0%5D.map%3CPoint%3E((i)%20%3D%3E%20%5B0%2C%200%5D)%0D%0A

Comment: And how do I make that work in a `JSX` environment? @adiga

Comment: Ah, compiler thinks `Point` is a component?

Comment: Yea, but briosheje’s suggestion works. Thanks anyway. You should make that an answer @briosheje

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of how `map` is typed.

The "official" definition is:

`map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];`

If you don't specify `U` then default `U[]` will be `[]` (same as `Array`).

The problem is that `[number, number]` is a *subset* of `Array` AND `map` without specifying `U` would mean the return type will be `Array`.

The two types not being compatible, you get that error.

Solution is to specify what `map` is allowed to return:

`const okToo: Points = [0].map<Point>(() => [0, 0])`

On the other hand I'd expect this to fail too:

`const notOk: Points = [0].map<Point>(() => [0, 0, 0])`

but on TypeScript 2.6.1 it's allowed. It's an error in 3.3 though, which is really nice.

Comment: Courtesy playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Point%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%0D%0Atype%20Points%20%3D%20Point%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ok%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C%200%5D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fail%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B0%5D.map%3CPoint%3E((i)%20%3D%3E%20%5B0%2C%200%5D)%0D%0A

Comment: @briosheje thanks! Question though: how do I use that to see the compile errors?

Comment: whenever you type something wrong, you just need to hightlight the row and it will show the error, like the original playground the OP provided: http://prntscr.com/mrcywk (playground here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Point%20%3D%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%5D%0D%0Atype%20Points%20%3D%20Array%3CPoint%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ok%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B%5B0%2C%200%5D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fail%3A%20Points%20%3D%20%5B0%5D.map(()%20%3D%3E%20%5B0%2C%200%5D)%0D%0A)

Comment: Cool! And it looks like in TS3.3 `[0, 0, 0]` is an error too.

Comment: Well, I guess it should be an error, since you're explicitly defining the return type (which **must** be of type "Point"). It's quite strange that it's allowed in 2.6.1, to me. Interesting :P.

Comment: Yeah I've got three production project codebases where I tested this but all of them are 2.*. 3.0 added better tuples: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-0/#richer-tuple-types